# child-exited signal after vte_terminal_fork_command_full

Tags: gtk3, fork

I'm using vte_terminal_fork_command_full function to start a new terminal with some command line arguments

```
vte_terminal_fork_command_full(
    VTE_TERMINAL(term->vte),
    VTE_PTY_DEFAULT,
    NULL,
    command_argv,
    NULL,
    G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &term->pid,
    &gerror))
```

command_argv contains the only one element

```
command_argv[o] = 'ls'
```

ls command has been executed well, but then terminal must be closed because child-exited signal has been handled with callback

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(term->vte), "child-exited",
 G_CALLBACK(child_exited), NULL);
```

Anybody knows why this signal was sent? And how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your ls child process exits, you get a child exited signal - nothing much to discuss here. If you want to keep the terminal window open, either don't connect the signal, or write a shell script that executes `ls` and `sleep 60`, call that script, and you'll habe 60 secs before the window closes.